# Asp.net core - Entity Framework core - add additional data to a view object while keeping it a Queryable

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, iqueryable, dynamic-linq, dynamic-linq-core

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<IQueryable<OurView>> GetInteractionRecordings(int pageNumber)
    {
        IQueryable<OurView> ourViews = _dbContext.OurView
            .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * 100)
            .Take(100)
            .AsQueryable();

        // One of the fields in OurView is a PhotoPath (string) that's not in the database.
        // We want to add that PhotoPath to every row without enumerating (function call for each row)
        // As we want to keep it a queryable

        return Ok(ourViews);
    }
```

Regardless of the solution, most importantly, what we want to avoid is the following:

Let's assume there are 500,000 records in the database table, enumerating all these records in the table before executing "Take" or the PhotoPath lookups.

We want it as a Queryable as we are utilizing Odata.

Comment: I didn't get a question. You know about `Select` - you can project many things.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - But doesn't Select return an IEnumerable?  From what I understand, an IQueryable is just a SQL Statement that then gets executed by the CLR.  If I use the select, won't the query actually execute before being returned by the end point?  We utilize odata, so imagine we grab 100 records at a time (as we are), but they apply an odata filter of LastName='justlooking', which is just 3 of those 100.  I'd like the Photo lookups to be on the three, not the 100.

Comment: And you are wrong. `Select` is a IQueryable extension, which returns IQuerybale. And it is a basic for generating proper LINQ query.

Comment: Geesh dude, All I'm telling you is what I was told, from someone who had me craft this question and post it under my account.  But looking at the intellisense now (based on your response), there were 10 options and some do return IQueryable and some do return IEnumerable.  So what do I know I guess.  But we want to do actual function calls to get a specific string.  I guess I'll see what happens.

Comment: I mean, it seems like making function calls from withing a .Select would lead to creating rows.  idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that via `Select`:

```cs
var ourViews = _dbContext.OurView
    .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * 100)
    .Take(100);

var photoPath = "SomePath";

var withAdditionalData = ourViews
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        // other fields

        PhotoPath = photoPath
    });
```

Comment: From my understanding, part of the issue was that he wasn't using Dynamic Linq.  With that package in place, Select is a working solution.